# How to get a hover function on a button element to work when using external CSS sheet?

Tags: html, css, hover

I am using an external CSS sheet and want to have a hover effect on my buttons, all examples I find when searching internet refer to inline CSS how can I get the effect to work when using an external CSS sheet, in the example below the #button is working but the #button:hover is not working

```
#button {
    margin: auto;
    font-size:24px;
    border-radius:8px;
    padding: 10px;
}

#button:hover{
    color:black;
}
```

Html code for the buttons is:

```
   <div id="nav">
        <button id="button">Clothing </button>
        <button id="button">Accessories</button>
        <button id="button">About</button>
        <button id="button">Contact</button>
        <button id="button">News</button>
    </div>
```

Comment: Probably because you are using an `id` with `#`, maybe you should do only button:hover { ... }.

Comment: Can you share a snippet of the html, showing element to which you want to apply the styles?

Comment: Can you post your HTML code, as the only problem that I could see potentially being wrong is you're specifying the wrong id. The `#button` will only work if in your html you have `id="button"`.

Comment: You're trying to change the text colour of the button to black on hover, but the colour is already black. If you change the code to: `color:red;` for example, it works fine. https://jsfiddle.net/gn2yevda/

Comment: ID values must be unique or they don't identify anything. It's required by the HTML spec, too. Use classes (sets of like things) instead.

Answer (score 0):

Try Writing it this way. So, instead of using 'color' attribute

```
#button:hover {background-color:black;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Color only changes the colour of the text.
Instead use background instead

Here's a codepen I created which might help you